# What is the new `filter(_:)` array method available since iOS 14.5?

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, sequence

There is a doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3392999-filter

The main question is what is the difference of this new method from the old `filter(_:)` sequence method (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter)?

Why do we need a new one at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. The specialization `Array.filter` simply calls the `Sequence.filter` default implementation.

The reason for having this specialization is of technical nature, the explanation can be found in https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/9741/commits/fd2ac31c6e8a6c18da0b40bfe1c93407b076e463:

> [stdlib] Adding RangeReplaceable.filter returning Self
>
> This overload
> allows `String.filter` to return a `String`, and not `[Character]`.
>
> In the other hand, introduction of this overload makes `[123].filter`
> somewhat ambiguous in a sence, that the compiler will now prefer an
> implementatin from a more concrete protocol, which is less efficient
> for arrays, therefore extra work is needed to make sure Array types
> fallback to the `Sequence.filter`.

Later the array method was moved to [`ArrayType.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/ArrayType.swift#L65) as part of the `_ArrayProtocol`, to which the “array types” `Array`, `ArraySlice`, and `ContiguousArray` conform:

```
extension _ArrayProtocol {
  // Since RangeReplaceableCollection now has a version of filter that is less
  // efficient, we should make the default implementation coming from Sequence
  // preferred.
  @inlinable
  public __consuming func filter(
    _ isIncluded: (Element) throws -> Bool
  ) rethrows -> [Element] {
    return try _filter(isIncluded)
  }
}
```